# Rails : ActionView::TemplateError (flag after width)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
ActionView::TemplateError (flag after width) on line #3 of vendor/plugins/exception_notification/views/exception_notifier/_environment.rhtml:
1: <% max = @request.env.keys.max { |a,b| a.length <=> b.length } -%>
2: <% @request.env.keys.sort.each do |key| -%>
3: * <%= "%*-s: %s" % [max.length, key, filter_sensitive_post_data_from_env(key, @request.env[key].to_s.strip)] %>
4: <% end -%>
5: 
6: * Process: <%= $$ %>
```

what? what does this error mean exactly, how does one fix it?

Comment: Did you mean `"%*s: %s"`?

Comment: I didn't mean anything, that's the error being spit out, I actually stopped caring about rails quite a while back so I've no idea about the outdated syntax. Are you saying removing the * in that plugin code is the fix?

Comment: Well, I don't know, you tell me what you want as output. I can't decide for you. If you take the star off, the code works but maybe not  as you expect ...

Comment: Sam, you say you stopped caring about rails a while back. Do you mean you really don't like doing this? That doesn't give much motivation to answer if I understand you correctly, because we're here to help you move forward in rails.

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: @mjnissim - no, I just mean I'm not up on rails or it's syntax (MrYoshiji's original response was edidted, it had some snarky syntax comment).

Comment: @MrYoshiji - thanks, removing the asterisk worked for me

Comment: @SamLuther you might ask MrYoshiji to post it as an answer then 'accept' it.